# Scrolling to v-expansion-panel opening

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to build a mobile small application using [v-expansion-panels](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels) to display a list.
The idea is that when the user adds a new item in such list it will open the new panel and scroll down to such new panel.

I found a [goTo()](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/scrolling/usage.vue#L84) method in the $vuetify variable, unfortunatly the v-expansion-panels transition (the "opening") take some time and the goTo() won't completely scroll down because of the scrollbar height changes.

So from my understanding I need to detect the end of the transition (enter/afterEnter hook).
Per the vuetifyjs documentation, I could hope to have a "transition" property on my component. (Which isn't the case anyway). But such property is only a string so I can't hook into it.

My other idea is to, somehow, find the transition component and hook into it. Unfortunatly I have trouble understanding el/vnode and the way vuejs is building is tree like the vue-devtool show and I can't get the transition component. When debugging (in the [enter hook callback of the transition](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/transitions/expand-transition.ts#L29)) it is like the component/el/vnode has a parent but isn't the child of anybody.

Is there a way to do what I'm looking for?

Here is a jsfiddler of what I currently do: https://jsfiddle.net/kdgn80sb/

Basically it is the method I'm defining in the Vue:

```
  methods: {
    newAlarm: function() {
      const newAlarmPanelIndex =  this.alarms.length - 1;

      this.alarms.push({title: "New line"});
      this.activePanelIndex = newAlarmPanelIndex;

      // TODO:
      this.$vuetify.goTo(this.$refs.alarmPanels[newAlarmPanelIndex]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Since the "opening" of the expansion-panel has a fixed duration - why not just add a setTimeout() and then scroll down?

Comment: I'm the kind of programmer that is looking for a solution that will follow events so it never came to my mind to use such simple solution... I don't think I will find the kind of solution I'm expecting so I will use your solution for sure! Thanks!

Comment: I guess sometimes it's just evaluating effort (time) and result. Keep an eye open if there are any issues with the setTimeout() method and heavily test it. If there should be issues you can always come back to the event-hooks later but it's better to keep going instead of being stuck on something that you have an alternative working version for; my opinion at least.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you should open manually panel and then use goTo with a timeout.
It works for me, just give some time to a panel to open.

```
<v-expansion-panels v-model="alarmPanels">
   <v-expansion-panel>
      <div id="example" />
   </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels> 


this.alarmPanels.push(0); // Use index of expansion-panel
setTimeout(() => {
    this.$vuetify.goTo(`#${resultId}`);
}, 500);
```